# JavaScript access event listener of geojson file with button

Tags: javascript

I have a little problem with event listeners.

I have a div 'map' for google maps, and some buttons with ids (button1, button2...).

```
<div id="map"></div>

<div id="all">
    <button class="geojsonbutton" id="button1">T B</button>
    <button class="geojsonbutton" id="button2">N O</button>
</div>
```

For the GoogleMap I load some GeoJSON files.

```
function loadLayer(){

for(i=0; i<2; i++){
    dataLayerArray[i] = new google.maps.Data();
    dataLayerArray[i].loadGeoJson('geojson/'+ i +'.geojson');
    dataLayerArray[i].setMap(map);
    }
}
```

Then add event listener

```
function loadListener(){

for(i=0; i<2; i++){
    dataLayerArray[i].addListener('click', testListener1);
    }
}
```

Which starts:

```
function testListener1(event){

console.log(event);
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
processPoints(event.feature.getGeometry(), bounds.extend, bounds);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

which works fine to center and zoom on my, so far, both geojson paths.
Now I would like to add some event handlers for the buttons to do the same effekt as the event listeners, but it wont work :(

I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button1').click(function(){
   console.log('button 1 clicked');
   $(dataLayerArray[0]).trigger('click');
    });
});
```

and many other versions of that, but it wont work, maybe anybody can help me please?

Comment: What specifically doesn't work? Is `button 1 clicked` not printed in the console. Is the `dataLayerArray[0]` `click` not triggered?

Comment: button 1 clicked is printed, but nothing else happens
If I try:

        $('#button1').trigger('click', dataLayerArray[0]);
    $('#button1').on('click', testListener1);
concole shows "event.feature is undefined"
I think problem is I can't name the event to call it, but not sure, just a js/jq beginner

Comment: isn't it possible to do someth. like: $('#button1').on('click', dataLayerArray[0].click);

Comment: or how can I pass the event here: $( "#button1" ).click(function() {
        testListener1();
    });